# How do i import data from database to website?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a phpmyadmin database that stores data from a simple form. Now i just have to make a page that shows all the answers nicely. How do i import data from that database to the new page?

Fixed: I learned some simple php and then i was good to go. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's loads of sample available online on how to retrieve and show data from a mysql database in php. Your question is too broad.

Comment: You start of by learning simple php and html, as Mr. White said, there are lots of samples / tutorials online to guide you.

Comment: @Mr.White I didn't find that much so i thought that i would ask here for some tangible answers.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284094/how-to-display-data-from-a-database, and go for the mysqli samples as the mysql ones are deprecated

Answer (score 2):

you need to write query to fetch data from your database and Display it on another page

Comment: Thanks, i googled that and it helped.